# Firestore snapshot properties undefined in cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm writing a small function to send an email based on document creation using multiple wildcards.

Weirdly, snapshopt.data() object has all its properties while printing them in the logs. However, when I try to access a property of this object, it is undefined (e.g. Cannot read property 'email' of undefined)

For the sake of the example, I will use console.log (it has been tested).

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();

type FullEvent = {
  email: string;
  date: string;
  localSlotFrom: string;
  localSlotFull: string;
  localDate: string;
  login: string;
  slotFrom: string;
  slotFull: string;
  ownerEmail: string;
  ownerName: string;
  name: string;
}

exports.createEmailTask = functions.firestore.document('/{rootCollection}/eventTypes/{eventTypeColId}/{eventTypeDocId}/fullEvents/{eventDocumentId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
      const fullEvent = snap.data() as FullEvent;
      // const { email } = snap.data() as FullEvent; // -> email is undefined as well this way

      console.log(fullEvent); // will have in logs the full object with defined properties (e.g. { name: "My event name", email: "myemail@example.com" }
      console.log('full event email ' + fullEvent.email); // Cannot read property 'email' of undefined 
      return;
```

The full function below

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();

type FullEvent = {
  email: string;
  date: string;
  localSlotFrom: string;
  localSlotFull: string;
  localDate: string;
  login: string;
  slotFrom: string;
  slotFull: string;
  ownerEmail: string;
  ownerName: string;
  name: string;
}

exports.createEmailTask = functions.firestore.document('/{rootCollection}/eventTypes/{eventTypeColId}/{eventTypeDocId}/fullEvents/{eventDocumentId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
      const { email, ownerEmail, name, ownerName, slotFull, localSlotFull, date, localDate } = snap.data() as FullEvent;

      console.log('ownerEmail ' + ownerEmail);

      const dateFormatted = new Date(date).toLocaleDateString('en-US', { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' });
      const localDateFormatted = new Date(localDate).toLocaleDateString('en-US', { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' });

      const p1 = admin.firestore().collection('mail').add({
        to: ownerEmail,
        message: {
          subject: `A new event has been scheduled with ${name}`,
          html: `A new event has been scheduled with ${name} on ${dateFormatted} between ${slotFull}`
        }
      });

      const p2 = admin.firestore().collection('mail').add({
        to: email,
        message: {
          subject: `Event scheduled with ${ownerName} confirmed!`,
          html: `The event with ${ownerName} has been confirmed and scheduled for the ${localDateFormatted} between ${localSlotFull}`
        }
      });

      return Promise.all([p1, p2]);
    });
```

for the information :

firebase-functions 3.11.0
firebase-admin 9.3.0

I've been trying different ways of printing the data. My assumption is that it has to do with promises.

Am I missing something?

UPDATES :

Logs :

```
createEmailTask
{"fullEvent":{"ownerEmail":"brieuc@iamremote.dev","date":"2020-11-03","localSlotFrom":"10:00","login":"johndoe","slotFrom":"16:00","slotFull":"16:00 - 17:00","name":"John Doe","localDate":"2020-11-03","localSlotFull":"10:00 - 11:00","email":"brieuc+johndoe@iamremote.dev","ownerName":"Kurniawan"}} 

createEmailTask
full event email undefined
```

Comment: I have tried you same settings but didn't have any issue and was able to access values of the created document. All what I think about is that there are some issues in the "FullEvent" interface. can you post its code?

Comment: @MethkalKhalawi I updated the code. I will try without the type again (which I did at the beginning) .

Comment: I tried without the type, I tried as well to delete the function and reupload. same. Your test was with a js or typescript config?

Comment: I tried with typescript. can you try this [code](https://gist.github.com/Methkal1990/107d2c309adb2d728fbbba1792d5d638)

Comment: Your code is working :).

Comment: are you sure you're getting data logged in this line `console.log(fullEvent);` ?

Comment: Yes, I updated the thread with the logs, you can see the full object that I logged (using JSON stringify, so it is a bit more readable through the logs).

Comment: I'm actually realizing that the event object has fullEvent as root, which is weird. Will try something and get back to you.

Comment: yeah, I can see. I wanted to tell you to try: `fullEvent.fullEvent.email` :)

Comment: Okay so there has been some refactoring yesterday on the front application that send this object to firestore. It was not obvious at first, now I see the issue ! Thank you for your help. It helped me to see it. I will probably delete this thread as I don't want to create noises :).

Comment: I think it's better to leave it to help other in some troubleshooting steps.

Comment: Alright :). If you want to post an answer, feel free.

Comment: just posted an answer. feel free to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we can see from the logs provided:

```
createEmailTask
{"fullEvent":{"ownerEmail":"brieuc@iamremote.dev","date":"2020-11-03","localSlotFrom":"10:00","login":"johndoe","slotFrom":"16:00","slotFull":"16:00 - 17:00","name":"John Doe","localDate":"2020-11-03","localSlotFull":"10:00 - 11:00","email":"brieuc+johndoe@iamremote.dev","ownerName":"Kurniawan"}}
```

it seems that you have a nested fullEvent object which has all the rest of the data. So to access your data you just need to:

```
console.log('full event email ' + fullEvent.fullEvent.email);
```

as per your code provided.